# Stored procedure result in the Detail section in the On Format event of a Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures, ms-access-2010

How could I call a stored procedure result in the Detail section in the On Format event of a Microsoft Access report, without calling the connection in each row ? because I think this is what i'm doing here, or maybe I'm trying to execute the SP in the wrong event? How can I do that ?

```
    Public Sub TestSPB()    


Dim conn As ADODB.connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set conn = New ADODB.connection

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxxxxxxx; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxx;Data Source=20.20.20.20"

With cmd

 .ActiveConnection = conn
 .CommandText = "TESTSP10"
 .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("Checkin", adDate, adParamInput, , Me.from1.Value)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("Checkout", adDate, adParamInput, , Me.to1.Value)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("IDHotel", adInteger, adParamInput, , Me.IDHOTELS.Value)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("canthabdbl", adInteger, adParamInput, , Me.cadbl.Value)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("cantchd", adInteger, adParamInput, , 0)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("canthab", adInteger, adParamInput, , 1)

.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("totalhab", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("Sum", adInteger, adParamOutput)

Set rst = .Execute
rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rst.Open cmd

End With

Dim tothabs as Double
Dim totsuma as Double
tothabs = cmd("totalhab")
totsum = cmd("Sum")

Set rst = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing


End Sub


'Detail section os report on format event 

Private Sub Detalle_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

TestSPB

Me.total.value = totalhabs
Me.sumade.value = totalsum

End Sub
```

Comment: Eh... Describe what you want to do. Then we can see what's the right event.

Comment: I'd like to show the result in of the SP in each row of a report in the detail section, all the inputs are in that section. If I just put the entire code on that section works ok but is extrematelly slow because I think that the connection is repeating in each one of rows

Comment: Well, that sounds like poor design... If you want to link the data to something you're displaying, you should use a query to join it. You can't do that with a stored procedure, though, but you shouldn't use a stored procedure to return data for every row. With this little information, I can't provide a proper design for your situation.

Comment: Well, I'll try other ways to get it , thank you very much anyway

Comment: That should just be in a query linked to your report - let the detail formatting take care of itself. Definitely shouldn't be running a SP for each row